# Impact of increasing MySQL wait_timeout

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

We currently have a low(?) timeout for MySQL queries, set to 15 seconds. Consequently, we get lots of timeouts when our server is under pressure. Unfortunately the CMS we're using handles these timeouts poorly, and sometimes caches the erroneous result from the database. We're also quite locked into this CMS so we cannot easily change.

I've been thinking about upping the time limit for MySQL, to see if this would improve the situation. However, I'm not sure about the ramifications of changing this setting: could it lead to clients hanging on for too long, hogging resources and eventually making the system even slower?

What is a good way to gauge if the performance of MySQL is better or worse after changing this parameter?

Also, if timeouts continue to happen, what is the best way to handle them? I'm thinking about throwing an exception for each failed query, and just throwing up a big error sign to our users. I'm thinking it might be better to "fail fast" instead of showing partially correct results.

Comment: How many users do use your site?

Comment: What version of MySQL? What CMS? What MySQL connection API (PDO, mysqli).

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.72. The CMS is a custom version of TYPO3 4.5. Standard (deprecated) mysql-connection.

Comment: Between 3000 and 5000 session per day, but some other websites are hosted on the same server and I don't have statistics for those sites.

Comment: Is it possible to setup varnish infront of the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sure MySQL query-handling is timing out, not php request-handling. As you surely know, that's an important distinction.

In an online system with naive users (that is, most of them!) it's usually counterproductive to abandon requests too soon and return errors. Why?  Because the users just try again, click, click, click, and so your server capacity gets burned up delivering garbage instead of useful results.

Fifteen seconds is shorter than usual for query timeout. You should try increasing it to a minute.

I suggest you try to work out which queries in your application are taking a long time. Probably only some take too long. You should attempt to optimize those requests, or make them slightly harder to use. If you increase your timeout, those offending queries will start to show up in the [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html).

Comment: I'm seeing "MySQL has gone away" in the logs, so it should be MySQL and not the PHP request-handling right? I guess I'll up the wait_timeout and see what effects there are, but I'm unsure what I should measure and how. If MySQL is timing out, the server must be occupied, but I'm unsure with what. I've looked in the slow log but I think it is more a case of death by a thousand paper cuts than any big offenders.